# powershell v2 function, how to have a default value for the 1st argument w/o naming the 2nd?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

the problem is quite simple. I have a function with two arguments and I would like to be able to call it without providing the first one when it has its default value, **without naming the second one**.
for example (this is not my real function but a simple example to show what I mean)

```
function foo 
{ param([int]$int=-1,[string]$str="''") 
  $int
  $str
}
```

I was hoping that forcing the type in the argument list will make PS bind the right value to the right argument but it seams that it's not the case

```
PS C:\> foo
-1
''
PS C:\> foo 1
1
''
PS C:\> foo 1 x
1
x
PS C:\> foo -str x
-1
x
PS C:\> foo x
foo : Impossible de traiter la transformation d'argument sur le paramètre «int». Impossible de convertir la valeur «x» en type «System.Int32». Erreur: «Le format de la chaîne
d'entrée est incorrect.»
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 5
+ foo x
+     ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData : (:) [foo], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,foo
```

is what I want possible in PS ?

## EDIT

here's a better example of what I'm trying to do

#### test.ps1

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter()]
    [string[]]$___where=@('*')
)

function InvokeOn {
[cmdletbinding()] 
param(
    [string[]]
    ${___names}=@('*'), 

    [scriptblock]
    ${___block}
)
    $___doExec = ($___names -contains '*')
    foreach($___name in $___names) { $___doExec = ($___doExec -or ($___where -contains $___name)) }
    if($___doExec) { &$___block }
}

$null = new-item alias:__LOG__ -value InvokeOn

__LOG__ c1    { Write-host '-- 1 --' }
__LOG__ c2    { Write-host '-- 2 --' }

__LOG__ c1,c2 { Write-host '-- 1 or 2 --' }

__LOG__ { Write-host 'always, defaulted' }
__LOG__  -___block { Write-host 'always, named'  }
```

and a few run

```
PS C:\> .\test
always, named
PS C:\> .\test c1
-- 1 --
-- 1 or 2 --
always, named
PS C:\> .\test c2
-- 2 --
-- 1 or 2 --
always, named
PS C:\> .\test c2,c1
-- 1 --
-- 2 --
-- 1 or 2 --
always, named
```

as you can see, `__LOG__ { Write-host 'always, defaulted' }` never fires as PS binds the scriptblock the wrong parameter.

Parameters names are on purpose complex and should not even be known by the developer using the aliased function.

Swapping the parameters is not practical as the scriptblock may be long and even for short ones, make the case where `__LOG__` will fire less readable.

## SOLUTION

applying majkinetor idea, I modified my code this way

```
function InvokeOn {
[cmdletbinding()] 
param(
    [string[]]
    ${___names} = @('*'),

    [scriptblock]
    ${___block}
)
    if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('___block')) { $___names,$___block = @('*'),[scriptblock]::create($___names[0]) }
    $___doExec = ($___names -contains '*')
    foreach($___name in $___names) { $___doExec = ($___doExec -or ($___where -contains $___name)) }
    if($___doExec) { &$___block }
}
```

and now it works as expected :)

Comment: Its not exactly the same, but you could switch the arguments position.

Comment: @majkinetor then the opposite wont work (`1` will be bound as a string to `$str`). The only way I can think of is by using [dynamic parameters](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/05/29/dynamic-parameters-in-powershell/) and attempt to parse the input as an integer.

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend that. It's an awful lot of overhead just for being able to avoid using the actual parameter name in some corner case.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen There is a simple way. See my answer.

Comment: By using that kind of "catchall parameter" you lose practically all advantages PowerShell's parameter handling provides. Might just as well drop `param()` entirely and evaluate the `$args` variable.

Comment: Sure, but it behaves like requested. I don't want to judge. There are valid reasons to want to have number of 'catch all' variables in specific contexts. Dropping to args also removes parameter name completition.

Comment: I added more info that may explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I maintain that it's a bad way to go about this, particularly when the second parameter doesn't seem to be optional in the first place, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: saying _this solution is bad_ is easy but what _better_ solution are you proposing?

Comment: Using named parameters on a well-defined API, obviously. Statements like *"Parameters names are on purpose complex and should not even be known by the developer using the aliased function"* make my skin crawl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
 function foo 
 { 
    param ($int=-1,[string]$str="''") 
    if ($int.gettype().Name -eq 'String') { $str = $int; $int = -1 }
    $int
    $str
 }
```

Notice - `$int` must not have type.

Comment: due to the more complex function I have (see edit) the test will be more tricky but I get the idea.

Comment: Nicely done; however, I suggest using `$int -is [string]` to test the type, which is both simpler and more robust.

Comment: You are totally right @mklement0, i totally forgot about `-is` operator. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

I consider hiding parameter names from the user and evaluating parameters solely based on their type a **Bad Idea™** and **strongly** recommend **against** doing this.

With that said, if you for some obscure reason you absolutely must have it this way, I'd drop named parameters entirely and use the `$args` [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) instead.

```
function foo {
  # define default values for your "parameters"
  $int = -1
  $str = "''"
  ...

  # evauluate $args and override default values
  foreach ($arg in $args) {
    switch ($arg.GetType().FullName) {
      'System.Int32'  { $int = $arg }
      'System.String' { $str = $arg }
      ...
      default { throw "Unrecognized type ${_}." }
    }
  }

  # handle missing arguments if required
  # Example:
  #   if ($args.Count -eq 0) { throw "No arguments provided." }

  ...
}
```